# Section style amsart

Tags: bold, amsart

I am using `amsart` for writing my seminar talk. I changed the section style form `scshape` to `bfseries` by writing

```
\renewcommand{\@secnumfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{2}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
```

However, this does also affect the style of things like `References` or `Index`. How can I prevent this? And why does this not affect the style of `Contents` as one can see here

[image]

Everything can be found here https://github.com/TheGeekGreek/harmonic_analysis.git. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want a different formatting for your regular `\section`s compared to the ToC and the References (and Index...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a style-switching macro that switches between the original style - `\originalsectionstyle` and your newly-defined style - `\newsectionstyle`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newsectionstyle}{%
  \renewcommand{\@secnumfont}{\bfseries}
  \renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{2}%
    \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
    {\normalfont\bfseries}}%
}
\let\oldsection\section% Store original \section
\let\old@secnumfont\@secnumfont% Store original \@secnumfont
\newcommand{\originalsectionstyle}{%
  \let\@secnumfont\old@secnumfont
  \let\section\oldsection
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newsectionstyle

\section{Linear Operators}\lipsum[1-10]

\section{The Real Method}\lipsum[11-20]

\section{The Complex Method}\lipsum[21-30]

\subsection{Hadamard's Three Lines Lemma}\lipsum[31-40]

\section{Interpolation of Analytic Families of Operators}\lipsum[41-50]

\originalsectionstyle

\begin{thebibliography}{x}
  \bibitem{abc} Abc
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

`\originalsectionstyle` reverts to the original formatting that was stored within the preamble. Here are their respective formatting settings if you wish to update them in a similar manner to what is done inside `\newsectionstyle`:

```
\def\@secnumfont{\mdseries}
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\scshape\centering}}
```

Comment: Perfect. Just one last question: How would I change in `\originalsectionstyle` the `\scshape` to `\bfseries`?

Comment: @TheGeekGreek: My approach for `\originalsectionstyle` was to revert back to the original definitions as set out by `amsart.cls`. However, you could redefine them in the same way you did in `\newsectionstyle`. I've updated my answer to include the original source definitions, where you can change `\scshape` to `\bfseries` and put is as-is inside `\originalsectionstyle`.

Comment: Many thanks. Everything works nice, but somehow the formatting of Contents is left unchanged. Even if I put `\originalsectionstyle` before `\tableofcontents`. Any idea?

Comment: @TheGeekGreek: That's because `\tableofcontents` sets things up in a special way. Do you want `\tableofcontents` to also work the same under `\newsectionstyle`?

Comment: What exactly does ''work the same'' mean? I just want the `\scshape` replaced by `\bfseries`, so basically contents should be `\originalsectionstyle` discussed above.